# In Windows 8.1 is it possible to use classic control panel dialogs (modal windows) instead of the Metro-style sidebar (e.g. for choosing WiFi)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, modern-ui

In Windows 8 many areas of the control panel were redesigned to use a Metro-style interface. For example connecting to a new WiFi network uses a full-screen sidebar like this:

[image]

This has several problems. For example if you lose focus of the sidebar it automatically closes. This means you can't copy and paste WiFi passwords for example.

Is it possible to revert to the classic Windows 7-style dialog boxes for the control panel?

Comment: You can also access the panel in question by managing the network adapter itself (i.e. `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`)

Comment: Copy the password before you open the sidebar.

Comment: @music2myear Not a solution but a workaround which only serves to enable poor UI design.

Comment: @WackGet - You already want to copy and paste the password.  Outside of using a third-party application to connect to the network like the shovelware HP uses, Windows has changed, unfortunately your using not using Windows 10 which significantly improve the user experience.  I absolutely will not suggest any software.